# OOP and Scalability

Tags: oop, concurrency, cloud, scalability

I was reading an article on ibm.com/developerworks (can't find the article now) about developing scalable software for the cloud.

Of course the main idea was going stateless. Nothing should contain state anymore and this was done by not having member data anymore. Every method should get its date by arguments passed to it.

One example was something like:

```
class NonScalableCircle {
    int radius;

    void setRadius(int radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public integer getDiameter() {
        return 2*radius;
    }
}
```

The explanation why this was not scalable was because you have to set the radius first and then call the diameter. So there is an order to it in order to work because methods work on the same data.

The scalable example was:

```
class ScalableCircle {
    public integer getDiameter(int radius) {
        return 2*radius;
    }
}
```

And of course it's true. Stateless scales way better.
Given this and the fact that OBJECT = data + behavior, my questions are:

Is OOP simply not good for highly-concurrent applications ?
Is OOP going to die and be replaced by Procedural Programming ?

Because even as it stands now, a lot of developers use the Anemic Domain Model and code the logic in services. There's not much OOP done really.

Answer (score 4):

While you can certainly improve scaling on a local level by removing state where possible, simply saying "get rid of state" doesn't solve much. User's expect (and largely need) things to be stateful.

Efficient scaling is rarely a matter of getting rid of state -- it's a matter of managing state. Especially in the case of distributed computing, it becomes mostly a matter of figuring on what state needs to be replicated on which machines for them to do particular pieces of a job.

In this respect, OO code (at least if it's *reasonably* well designed) tends to be a really good thing -- a reasonably well-defined object defines virtually all the state that needs to be replicated for that kind of object to work on that machine.

Contrary to popular belief, functional programming isn't necessarily a major improvement. First, FP doesn't eliminate state (at all). It does make individual parts of the state immutable, but this isn't necessarily any major improvement either, since it can lead to simply removing one part of the state and replacing it with something "new" that has the same name but a different value. In such cases, the immutable state can be a distinction without a difference.

Where OO makes a fairly substantial difference is in making state sufficiently explicit that a designer is (almost) forced to think about the state necessary for a given object. This tends to implicitly encourage minimizing that state to a large degree. I should also mention that in this respect, too much convenience can be a bad thing -- a language that (for example) makes it trivial to generate code for serialization regardless of the amount of state in an object makes it that much easier for an object to include more state. When/if the programmer's work is proportional (at least in part) to the amount of state, it gives him at least a little encouragement to minimize the state.

In any case, objects break state up into fairly small, identifiable chunks that are usually fairly easy to manage. Far from making parallelization and (especially) distribution more difficult, this actually makes it easier, unless the code is just *really* badly designed. Of course, no language, paradigm, methodology, or much of anything else, can prevent bad design, but OO gives a designer the tools to do a good job and help make distribution and scaling substantially more practical.

Answer (score 3):

> Is OOP going to die and be replaced by Procedural Programming ?

No there's nothing wrong with OOP. You may need to change your attitude to how you handle OOP a little though. I'll also point out that it's significantly easier to write massively scale concurrent software if you use a functional rather then procedural paradigm.

What your describing in terms of stateless-ness is the beginning of [Monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)

Start messing around with [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) to see how you massively scale, correctly.

> Is OOP simply not good for highly-concurrent applications ?

OOP isn't the problem, Imperative languages are. You need [continuation passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and other functional patterns to be able to scale massively. Functional programming encourages state-less design so it's far easier to scale.

But OOP still has it's place, a lot of functional languages are meta languages and have OO in them.

Another method of achieving better scaling is [non-blocking IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

Another issue is that a lot of Enterprise / Business systems build ontop of J2EE & .NET which don't really encourage techniques for massive scaling outside of "buy more servers".

If you want to truly take advantage of making your code scale properly and highly take a paradigm switch.

I also read concurrency and scaling as running a couple hundred processes and handling a couple thousand connections simultaneously.

Comment: "No, you cant do procedural and highly concurrent."  WTF?  This is nonsense.  The vast majority of highly concurrent software in existence is procedural, and the vast vast vast majority of highly parallel software in existence is procedural.  In _principle_, functional gives advantages this way, as people have beein pointing out for 25 years, but to say anything stronger than that is completely out of touch with reality.

Comment: @JonathonDursi your right, the statement was far too strong. I've adjusted it and toned it down significantly. I meant it's difficult to do high concurrency in a procedural manner. It also depends what level of concurrency / parallelism were talking about, if it's 10 or 1000.

Comment: Fair enough.  But it's hard to do high levels of concurrency in _any_ manner :)

Comment: @JonathanDursi it get's pretty easy if the language was build for it, spend a weekend hacking around with Erlang at some point.

Comment: "If you want to truly take advantage of making your code scale properly and highly take a paradigm switch." As said on stackoverflow built on ASP.NET.

Comment: @Raynos: I have; I've even tried using it for scientific computing.  But it's still not _easy_ to get to 10k tasks efficiently.   The problems that are well suited to Erlang are easy to express in Erlang (but performance tuning, as ever, remains a challenge); but problems that aren't well suited to Erlang are very hard to write in Erlang.  Which is true of any tool, of course; there are no magic bullets.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Just pulling up [some jaws benchmarks](http://www.sics.se/~joe/apachevsyaws.html), it's just happily sitting at 80k parallel connections. @ChrisMarisic A paradigm switch is what's needed for massive scaling, but SO doesn't need massive concurrency scaling. simply use the best tool for the job. I presume SO design started in '06 so ASP.NET wasn't a _bad_ choice.

Comment: @JonathanDursi the point was the massive difference between procedural and functional approaches to a similar problem. Any problem that requires a scaling solution can probably be handled in a functional manner. The main problem is that it's very hard for an industry to make a paradigm switch. I don't think it's an issue of "problems aren't well suited to erlang" but more of problem with difficulty in terms of thinking about how to handle the problem so that it scales. Like you said "careful planning".

Comment: @JonathanDursi It's just a matter of building up a skilled work force that knows how to solve large real world problems using these languages. All the theory is there, the industry just hasn't adapted to use it yet, and it might never do. We might have our magic silver bullet in the next 20 years ;)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, nobody knows.   There isn't much concensus yet on the "right" way to write serial software, and parallel and concurrent programming is that much more difficult.

The entire key to efficient parallel computation at scale is distribution of data, and so there's an argument to be made that by encapsulating the data too early in the design process -- or by taking a data encapsulation that makes sense for small numbers of tasks, and naively hoping that scales up -- you are hurting scalability.   Maybe that means OO has one hand tied behind its back in writing scalable code, but maybe it just means OO, like everything else, requires careful planning to be massively scalable.

Comment: +1 "but maybe it just...requires careful planning to be massively scalable." understatement of the year award ;)

Comment: +1 There is a lack of tried and tested methods in this sector.